# Heapsize overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting following error as a log in the .Net application.

> APC : GCHeapSizeMB=1507,AdminGCHeapLimitMB=1500. Heap size cannot be
>   reduced to desired level.

I understand that there is overflow in heap memory but can someone tell me how to avoid / manage this issue.

I came across an class called MemoryFailingPoint in System.Runtime but would like to know how much memory available and want to mange it programatically.

Comment: Googling for "Heap size cannot be reduced to desired level" gives 0 results, so this suggests the error is coming either from your own code or from some third-party component. You might need to provide the underlying .Net exception, or some more context.

Comment: show the code where application fails

Comment: problem is, i'm unable to find where it fails. its throwing error but page yields successful result. Just its logging it. Which is what i want to identify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged myself and found there seems to be lot of file handles can be disposed and temporary memories which is not required can be disposed. So, I have did the same and its seems to be some what less. However i need to resolve or should log with zero errors in order to resolve this across the project which is a quite tedious task.

Thanks for all your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If there is indeed a problem with memory, then you should use memory profiler to debug the issue. Googling for `memory profiler .NET` would give you a list. Of course I recommend one from JetBrains because I work there :)